# Null pointer exception - Apache Spark Dataset left outer join

Tags: apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to learn spark dataset (spark 2.0.1). Below left outer join is creating Null pointer exception.

```
case class Employee(name: String, age: Int, departmentId: Int, salary: Double)
case class Department(id: Int, depname: String)
case class Record(name: String, age: Int, salary: Double, departmentId: Int, departmentName: String)
val employeeDataSet = sc.parallelize(Seq(Employee("Jax", 22, 5, 100000.0),Employee("Max", 22, 1, 100000.0))).toDS()
val departmentDataSet = sc.parallelize(Seq(Department(1, "Engineering"), Department(2, "Marketing"))).toDS()

val averageSalaryDataset = employeeDataset.joinWith(departmentDataSet, $"departmentId" === $"id", "left_outer")
                               .map(record => Record(record._1.name, record._1.age, record._1.salary, record._1.departmentId , record._2.depname))

averageSalaryDataset.show()
```

**16/12/14 16:48:26 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 12)
java.lang.NullPointerException**

This is because While doing left outer join it is giving null values for record._2.depname.

How to handle this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by using---

```
val averageSalaryDataset1 = employeeDataSet.joinWith(departmentDataSet, $"departmentId" === $"id", "left_outer").selectExpr("nvl(_1.name, ' ') as name","nvl(_1.age, 0) as age","nvl(_1.salary, 0.0D) as salary","nvl(_1.departmentId, 0) as departmentId","nvl(_2.depname, ' ') as departmentName").as[Record]
averageSalaryDataset1.show()
```

Comment: Although this will probably work it is a very poor solution :o ! I don't understand why the join isn't giving back an options of the case class so that it is easy to check.

Answer (score 1):

null can be handled using if..else condition.

```
val averageSalaryDataset = employeeDataSet.joinWith(departmentDataSet,   $"departmentId" === $"id", "left_outer").map(record => Record(record._1.name, record._1.age, record._1.salary, record._1.departmentId , if (record._2 == null) null else record._2.depname ))
```

After the join operation, the resulting dataset columns are stored as Map(key-value pairs) , and in map operation, we are calling the keys but the key is "null' when you are calling record._2.depName which is why the exception.

```
val averageSalaryDataset = employeeDataSet.joinWith(departmentDataSet,   $"departmentId" === $"id", "left_outer")
```

[Dataset after left join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mg2d.png)